# Where should custom Responders go in a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, responders

I need to implement a custom Responder under "Module Responders", however, I am not sure where such code should live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically what the `lib` directory is for.

Just be sure to update your `config/application.rb` file to include `lib` in `autoload_paths`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually drop them in `app/responders`