# How can I customize Rails 3 validation error json output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-api

By default calling rails.model.to_json

Will display something like this:

```
{"name":["can't be blank"],"email":["can't be blank"],"phone":["can't be blank"]}
```

Instead of message i need to generate some status code that could be used on service client:

```
[{"field": "name", "code": "blank"}, {"field": "email", "code": "blank"}]
```

This approach is very similar to github api v3 errors - http://developer.github.com/v3/

How can I achieve this with Rails?

Comment: Another similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911470/api-errors-customization-for-rails-3-like-github-api-v3. Also with no answer =\

Comment: In this thread, rails "Responders" are used to achive that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911470/api-errors-customization-for-rails-3-like-github-api-v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your model you can modify the way as json operates. For instance let us assume you have a ActiveRecord model `Contact`. You can override `as_json` to modify the rendering behavior.

```
def Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json
    hash = super

    hash.collect {|key, value|
      {"field" => key, "code" => determine_code_from(value)} 
    }
  end

end
```

Of course, you could also generate the json in a separate method on `Contact` or even in the controller. You would just have to alter your render method slightly.

```
render @contact.as_my_custom_json
```

Comment: Value is string like this "Can't be blank". May there is some way to get error type instead of message.

Comment: What do you mean by error type? All validations raise the same error. The key is the field that is causing the error, and the value is the message. What do you want the "code" in your example to be?

Comment: If you don't use the "Can't be blank" message for anything else, simply override the message in your model class to be what you want the code to be. For example, `validates_numercality_of :zip_code, "320"`

Comment: Hmm... overriding message in declaration is good idea! I need this to implement api and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, when you render the output, in your case JSON content, add the following :

```
render :json => @yourobject, :status => 422 # or whatever status you want.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Dominic, I have asked about different problem. Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: And it is still unclear, because with my solution you have exactly what you asked for (http://developer.github.com/v3/). You will have something like : HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Content-Length: 35

 {"message":"Problems parsing JSON"}